# R: creating a package with files needed in the package functions

Tags: r

I would like to build an R-package. The main function of this package calculates some characteristics of a molecule. In order to be able to calculate these characteristics, the main function requires besides the user-input additional information.  The additional information needs to be read in as it takes too much time to calculate it each time I use the main-function.

Because of this, I saved the additional information in two files. I can read them in in the main-function by using `read.delim()`, but if I would like to use the main function several times, the computation time is slowed down because I need to read in these files every time again. Is there some work-around which allows me to read-in these files only once?

Simplified example of the function:

```
main <- function(molecule){

nbAtoms <- length(molecule)
info1 <- read.delim("info1.txt", header=F, dec=",", quote="")
info2 <- read.delim("info2.txt", header=F, dec=",", quote="")
char <- sqrt(info1+info2)/nbAtoms
return(char)
}
```

Comment: How about saving them as `RData` files as part of your package and loading them with `data`?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot Thanks for the suggestion. Reading in the txt files takes 18.22s while reading in the `RData` file with `load` takes 0.51s.